# Stop app window overlapping Windows start bar

Tags: c++, winapi

On my Win7 PC I have the start-bar running vertically, it's about 60px wide. In my win32 application, the created window always appears overlapping the start bar, which looks bad - I just use (0,0) as the top-left position for the window.

How should I be doing it to get (0,0) relative to the desktop, taking the Start Bar into account? Is there a flag, or do I manually need to look up a metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here. You don't want to use a hard-coded value like (0,0). That might not even be visible on a multi-monitor system. As you have discovered, you should try to avoid  overlapping with the taskbar or other appbars. If there are multiple monitors you should try and start on the monitor where the user has most recently interacted.

There is a simple way to make much of this happen for free. Pass `CW_USEDEFAULT` as the `x` and `y` coordinates when you call `CreateWindow`. This will let the window manager do the hard work of making your window appear in a sensible location.

---

You can get the system to tell you the coordinates of the work area. The work area is that part of the desktop that does not contain the taskbar or other appbars. Call [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing `SPI_GETWORKAREA`.

> Retrieves the size of the work area on the primary display monitor. The work area is the portion of the screen not obscured by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars. The pvParam parameter must point to a `RECT` structure that receives the coordinates of the work area, expressed in virtual screen coordinates.
>   To get the work area of a monitor other than the primary display monitor, call the [`GetMonitorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: You are right about proper multi-monitor support, but in this simple case I think `CW_USEDEFAULT` is what I'm after to avoid 'illegal' placements? Can you confirm that's better then Raymond's `SetWindowPlacement` answer?

Comment: @John I'd hesitate to say my suggestion was better than that of someone like [Raymond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/). It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. I think Raymond has addressed your direct question whereas I have perhaps looked at it from a broader perspective.

Comment: @John `CW_USEDEFAULT` is a good start but one day you may wish to enhavnce your program by getting it to remember where it was when it last closed and then to resume at that location the next time it starts.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SetWindowPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633544%28VS.85%29.aspx). The (0,0) for that function excludes the taskbar and any other appbars.